# Set maximum height of control based on height of other controls (using CalcBinding)

Tags: wpf, xaml, element-binding, calcbinding

I have a `TextBlock` and three `Grid`s, contained inside another `Grid`.  Each inner grid contains a `TextBlock` in the first row and `DataGrid` in the second.  The data in the datagrids has a variable number of records.

```
<Grid Name="gridOuter">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />  // <-- x3 
    ...
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Contents" />

  <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="innerOne" MinHeight="50" MaxHeight="???">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Heading One</TextBlock>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
      <DataGrid Name="dataGridOne">
        <DataGridColumns> 
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Title}" /> 
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Description}" /> 
        <DataGridColumns> 
      </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
  ...
  <!-- x2 more with Grids named innerTwo and innerThree, with contained
       DataGrids named dataGridTwo and dataGridThree, respectively
  -->

</Grid>
```

I wish to set the `MaxHeight` of each of the inner grids to equal the `ActualHeight` of the outer grid, minus the sum of the `MinHeight`s of the other two inner grids.

I'm using [CalcBinding](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding), but am open to any other solution.

I'm hoping I can do something like:

```
MaxHeight="{cb:Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=gridOuter
         - (cb:Binding MinHeight, ElementName=dataGridTwo 
           + cb:Binding MinHeight, ElementName=dataGridThree)}"
```

Is this possible with CalcBinding, and if so, what is the correct syntax - if not, is it possible some other way?